# Apple Watch show custom tile maps

Tags: ios, apple-watch, apple-maps

How can I display custom WMS tile map on AppleWatch? Or is it even possible? I'm using Objective-C. MKOverlayRenderer doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the current watch kit, you'll have to pre-render and image and send that to the watch.